# Map port of container without exposing to host in docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

I have

```
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  superservice:
    image: superservice
    ports:
      - # ?
```

`superservice` is very super, but I simply pulled it from the Docker hub and its port cannot be configured when creating a container. The default port is `8080`. But that is already in use. How do I change it to `8081`? I do NOT want it to be accessible from the host, that is why `- "8081:8080"` is not desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you would have to change the port `superservice` is running on by either changing its configuration, or if possible, change the `command` or `entrypoint` it runs on start and pass the new port as an argument.

Although, if `superservice` does not have to be reachable from the host then you should have no problem referencing it as `http://superservice:8080` from inside the api container.